# Question about Homeomorphism and compactness.

Tags: general-topology

I'm currently studying Introduction To Topology and I have two questions I'd appreciate help with!

Prove or disprove the following:
1- $(\mathbb{R}, \mathfrak{u}) $ is homeomorphic to $([0,1], \mathfrak{u}_{[0,1]})$?

I know that for any $(a,b)$, $\hspace{0.1cm}$ $((a,b), \mathfrak{u}_{(a,b)})$ is homeomorphic to $(\mathbb{R}, \mathfrak{u})$ $\hspace{0.5cm}$(if its not clear what I mean by $\mathfrak{u}$ it's usual topology).

2- Every subset of compact topological space is compact. I know this one is wrong but I couldn't think of any counterexample.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: a) $[0,1]$ cannot be homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$ because one is compact and the other is not, but if the interval was $(1,0)$, then yes they are homeomorphic b) What about $(0,1)\subset [0,1]$?

Comment: @Alessandro thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1.Homeomorphism(in fact the image of a compact set under a continuous map is compact) preserves compactness. In other words a homeomorphism maps a compact set to a compact set.

$[a,b]$ is compact and hence if $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ is a homeomorphism, then $f([a,b])=\Bbb{R}$ should have been compact under the usual topology which it is not.
Thus these two spaces are not homeomorphic.

2. $(a,b)$ is a subset of the compact set $[a,b]$ in $\Bbb{R}$ with usual topology. But $(a,b)$ is not compact as it is not closed. (A compact set in a Hausdorff space must be closed).